# Определение языка пользователя в IE / Edge с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

Задача состоит в том, чтобы определять установленный язык пользователя в браузере, который имеет наивысший приоритет.
Имеем:

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage;
```

В Opera, Chrome определяется язык верно и определяет первый в списке. В IE/Edge определяется язык, который установлен в "региональных особенностях", т.е. нет никакой разницы, какие были установлены приоритеты языков по пути "Панель управления\Все элементы Панели управления\Язык". (OS Windows 10).
Определение нужно для того, чтобы правильно подсветить текущий язык веб-приложения при первом посещении, далее это делается на основе данных с cookie.
Есть ли возможность решить вопрос ?

Comment: Странности осла и его приемника -- это уже притча о том, каким браузером не надо быть.

Comment: @Other, не надо на клиенте определять язык. Только на этой неделе читал статью на эту тему.

Comment: ОК, тогда каким образом мне изменить стиль кнопки смены языка ?

Comment: @xrk, изменить на что?

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: изменить стиль (цвет, размер, шрифт и т.п.)

Comment: @Qwertiy, чойта так? Т. е. я знаю, но интересно узнать Ваше мнение.

Comment: @Other, вроде как он не тот язык отдавать может. И вообще, если есть специально придуманный механизм (http-заголовок), то нет никаких причин городить костыли через другие механизмы.

Comment: в заголовке все верно отдает, а JS выводит совсем не то. Проблема именно в IE/Edge

Answer (score 0):

> правильно подсветить текущий язык веб-приложения при первом посещении

Вообще-то это должен сделать сервер на основе http-заголовка `Accept-Language`:

```
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4
```

[Ещё вопрос на эту тему.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539842/178988)

> далее это делается на основе данных с cookie

Вот сервер на основе первого запроса и должен их сформировать.

Comment: Спасибо, поковыряю сервер.